# How to access Laravel 4 errors in TwigBridge?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, twig

I've installed TwigBridge for Laravel 4 and I am trying to adapt some templates I've already got from Blade to Twig.

I want display some validation errors at the top of a view.

I had the following in Blade (which worked OK):

```
@if (isset($errors))
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I've tried to convert it to Twig but nothing gets displayed.

```
{% if errors %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

However, if I try:

```
{{ errors }}
```

I do get some output:

> {"name":["The name field is required."]}

What do I need to change in order to get it to work?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I worked it out after I looked at the code in Illuminate/Support/MessageBag:

```
{% if errors.any %}
    {% for error in errors.all %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The same for Laravel 5.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
{{ errors.first('email') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following to target an `email` field...

```
{{ errors.toArray['email'][0] }}
```

Not sure it's a great approach.